# Mobile padding issue

Tags: css, mobile, web, padding, squarespace

I have inserted some spacing between the map and the "Used By Thousands Of Canadians" in the middle of my website, which it looks like I have room for. But when I do this and view the website on my Iphone it shows that it doesn't have any room and the image is push away from the text. Can someone see what is causing this and show me a corrective action. Thanks for your time

www.jobspark.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the % instead of the px unit 
or use @media and specify dimensions for the smart phone resolution
[@media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

[CSS @media for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

I hope that will help 
PS: under the @media you can specify changes only for certain elements, ID or classes so you don't have to redesign the hole page (as far as I know) so don't be shy to give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Changing it to a % did the trick!